# Run Excel macro automatically upon excel file opening

Tags: vba, excel

I have a personal workbook macro written in excel vba... I want that macro run automatically as soon as a particular named excel file is opened by any user.  And that it should not run if it is already been run on that excel file earlier..

Comment: And what have you tried till now?

Comment: http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/auto-run-macros.htm

Comment: I am a newbie in vba .. That's why i don't know how to do it.. Right now i have to run the macro from developer tab of the excel and its like manual task.. That's why i want this task automated like if the excel file name is same as existed macro name then it will run that macro on this raw excel data but only for 1 time if possible..

Answer (score 2):

Open excel vba editor: Shift+F11. In MsExcelObjects doubleclick on "This Workbook".On the right side write this code and adapt it to your needs:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
 If SheetX.cells(x,y) = 0 then 'adapt SheetX and cell(x,y) to your needs.
 'execute your code here
  SheetX.cells(x,y)=1 'placeing an indicator if program runs, so it wont run another time it starts.
 end if
end sub
```

Comment: Through above code macro will not run automatically just by opening an excel file.

Comment: Yes it would run automatically. Each time you open a workbook!

Comment: Jelovac code will work,if the code is written in the same workbook for which it has to be executed. In case if you want to use for different workbook then you first need to read the file from directory, open it, then call this module.